# Há alguma forma de estender a propriedade "transform", para evitar perdas ou repetições?

Tags: css

No CSS, muitas vezes eu gosto de utilizar algumas "classes modificadoras" para estender funcionalidades.

Exemplo:

```
.btn{
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}

.btn.btn-outlined{
   background-color: transparent;
   color: red;
}
```

Eu tenho uma dúvida quanto a propriedade `transform`. As vezes coloco algumas coisas lá, para normalizar a centralização do elemento, por exemplo. Porém ao usar uma outra classe para modificar a principal, sempre acabo tendo que redeclarar tudo de novo.

Exemplo:

```
.principal{
    transform: rotateX(25deg) translateX(-50%) scale(1.2);
}
```

No caso acima, se eu quisesse adicionar algo a mais no `transform`, por exemplo, um `skew`, eu não poderia fazer isso, sem ter que praticamente copiar a linha inteira.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma solução menos repetitiva no CSS sobre essa situação do `transform`.

Algumas propriedades costumam ter longas declarações, como `font` e `background`. Alguém poderia declarar um `font: 12px arial bold`. Porém a maioria delas possui modificadores como `background-color`, `background-size`, `background-repeat`, `font-size` ou `font-weight` que facilitam trocar uma parte da propriedade.

Queria saber se  existe alguma coisa assim para `transform`.

Comment: Com preprocessadores é possível estender um seletor, mas acredito que ele sobrepõe o estilo base, talvez com algum plugin seja possível contornar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem uma forma sim, é usando o `Matrix()` ou `Matrix3d()`!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A diferença é que no `matrix3d()` vc habilita o plano `Z`, podendo fazer efeitos de perspectiva e complicando um pouco a matriz com mais informações...

> matrix (a, b, c, d, tx, ty)
>
> matrix3d (a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3, a4, b4, c4, d4)

Aqui tem um exemplo, repare que só tem o `transform matrix`, porém ele tem vários atributos do `transform` ao mesmo tempo, como `translate`, `skew`, `scale`, `rotate` e por ai vai.

**Veja que aqui temos exatamente essa situação, e repare como é possível transforma vários atributos de `transform` em uma matriz**

```css
#object1 {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: 
                rotate(15deg) 
                translateX(20px)  
                scale(1.5, 2.6) 
                skew(220deg, -150deg) 
                translateX(20px);

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

#object2 {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: 
                matrix(1.06, 1.84, 0.54, 2.8, 20, 20);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="object1"></div>
<div id="object2"></div>
```

O difícil é entender como a matriz funciona, como não é minha especialidade, vou deixar um link de pessoas que explicariam melhor que eu :D

- https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d

Aqui tem um simulador para construir a matriz automaticamente
https://www.useragentman.com/matrix/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um código de exemplo usando animação junto com matriz (o código não é meu é só para fins didáticos):

```css
CSS
html {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  /* Centering content */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  
}
.foo {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: #ff8c66;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
   /* Setting up animation for better demonstration */
  animation: MotionScale 2s alternate linear infinite;
}

@keyframes MotionScale {
  from {
    /*
      Identity matrix is used as basis here.
      The matrix below describes the
      following transformations:
        Translates every X point by -50px
        Translates every Y point by -100px
        Translates every Z point by 0
        Scales down by 10%
    */
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      -50,-100,0,1.1
    );
    
  }
  50% {
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,.01,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      0,0,0,0.9
    );
  }
  to {
     transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      50,100,0,1.1
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
   Take the blue pill
</div>
```